# Is Shadowmarch in Osten Ard

Tags: tad-williams

I am just wondering, is there any cannon evidence that the Shadowmarch is in Osten Ard?

According to this map, it doesn't appear to be.

[image: Osten Ard Map]

However this could be because Shaowmarch was written after Sorrow, Memory and Thorn. Is there any other 'in universe' evidence that the two universes do not simply share a similar naming convention?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.tadwilliams.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/worldmap.jpg) appears to be a map of the continent that Shadowmarch is set on.

[image]

As you can see, there isn't really even a slight correlation between the two maps.

There might be the possibility that these are two different parts of the same world, but it seems unlikely, as the settings have many details not in common (their races, for one), and Tad Williams has never linked the two.

There is currently a sequel series to *Memory Sorrow and Thorn* being written and released, so potential still exists for them to be welded somehow.

Comment: I have not yet read the *Shadowmarch* books (it's on my to do list, but I tend to sour on Williams on and off), so if I'm in error, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading Shadowmarch for the first time. And he does mention Cockindrills, which were animals also mentioned in Memory, Sorrow and Thorn. So maybe the other side of the globe or something.

Comment: So do the two universes share similar naming conventions, or is there evidence there the same place?